# Copy the entire master branch from one GitHub enterprise server to another GitHub enterprise server in a different location

Tags: github

We have two hosted GitHub enterprise servers on VMWare servers in a distinct location. We would like to copy all master branch from one GitHub enterprise server to another GHE (maybe every day once). Also, we need to configure alerts to notify in case of copy failure, network issues, etc.

Could you please help me to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

git clone --bare https://github-dev.assr.com/assr-ghactions/setup-java.git

git push --mirror https://github-qa.assr.com/assr-ghactions/setup-java.git

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.